# In LDAP how does one know which OID arc to use in the object identifier?

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm new to LDAP and I'm looking to create a new user schema to hold credentials and personal information.

I've found several examples of how to do this ([this](https://guillaumemaka.com/2013/07/17/openldap-create-a-custom-ldap-schema/) for example) and they all have a string such as `1.3.6.1.4.1.7165.1.1.1` which I think is the OID arc.

The [docs](https://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/391.html) *seem* to suggest that this is something I need to register for? Is that correct or have I misunderstood?

Say my DN is `dc=foo,dc=bar,dc=ie` how do I know what OID arc to use to create a member schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you can register an OID arc by getting an IANA enterprise ID in OID arc 1.3.6.1.4.1.

For details see ldapwiki article: [How To Get Your Own OID](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/How%20To%20Get%20Your%20Own%20OID)

The enterprise numbers are publicly available as [PRIVATE ENTERPRISE NUMBERS](https://www.iana.org/assignments/enterprise-numbers/enterprise-numbers).

Comment: I want to add that there are no fees involved and registration is 100% free as of today.

Comment: Thanks for that. Are the OID arcs public information? If I register my org will it be obvious that my org is using LDAP?

Comment: Yes, enterprise numbers are public. I've edited my answer accordingly.